# Celery Flower -- Adding a Remote Task Worker doesnt display in flower

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I've got Celery flower + rabbitmq setup running on my local box with the UI on localhost:5555 displaying an empty list of workers. Now, on a remote machine I have a celery flower connected to the same broker like the following:

server (local setup): celery flower --broker=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//
remote:  celery flower --broker=amqp://smurf@remotemachine:5672//

The connection is successful when I  view the connections tab in rabbitmq, however when flower does not list the worker through the web-ui.  Why would it connect successfully to rabbitmq but not show on flower?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just solved it. Silly me, you must run the remote machine with the command "celery worker --broker=amqp://....//

Comment: Hey @pratik, could you elaborate on how you set the whole thing up? I have many workers running on different EC2 instances and one common Redis [Elasticache] instance they use as broker. I have set up flower inside Vagrant [along with celery and redis] and I want to monitor all the remote workers with it. I have created a tunnel for the remote Redis port `6379` to localhost `6389` and I can access it via RedisDesktopManager. But when I run `celery flower -A --broker_api=http://localhost:6389/api/` it says `error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Comment: Hey mate - this was a little over  4 years ago, and since then I have not used celery or rmq, these were days before docker existed.  I generally try and make a concerted effort to assist, pay it forward, but in this instance I don't think I can help.  Please accept my apology!